# Join result of two complex SQL Query by SPECIFIC CRITERIA

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

There are two queries, below are the queries along with result in a case is given.

In the first query result, in **5th row, from southbound to northbound, there are 5 semi-trucks and in 7th row, 22 trucks.**

In the **2nd query**, there are two object types. If we consider the 4th row, the row says that, **From Southbound to Northbound, there are 3 semi-trucks and 3 trucks**

What have to be done is, **From 2nd result as we get 3 Semitruck, they will be added up in the new result with the first query's 5th row. So total Semi-Truck will be 8 and similarly, Truck will be 25 (7th row)**

Additionally, if there is no common row, that will be added as a new row in the result.

**1st :**

```
select 
    count(v.ObjectType) o, 
    v.ObjectType, v.EnterDirection, v.Direction 
from 
    validobjects v 
where 
    processinfoid = 1 
    and Isactive = 1 
    and v.ObjectType <> 'None' 
    and (v.EnterDirection = 'SouthBound' OR 
         v.EnterDirection = 'EastBound' OR 
         v.EnterDirection = 'NorthBound' OR 
         v.EnterDirection = 'WestBound' OR 
         v.EnterDirection = 'SouthEastBound' OR 
         v.EnterDirection = 'SouthWestBound' OR 
         v.EnterDirection = 'NorthEastBound' OR 
         v.EnterDirection = 'NorthWestBound')
group by 
    v.ObjectType, v.EnterDirection, v.Direction
```

**Result:**

[image]

**2nd:**

```
select 
    count(v.objecttype1) o1,
    count(v.ObjectType2) o2, 
    v.ObjectType1, v.ObjectType2, 
    v.EnterDirection, v.Direction 
from 
    ValidObjects v 
where 
    v.ValidObjectID in (select ValidObjectID 
                        from validobjects v 
                        where processinfoid = 1 
                          and Isactive = 1 
                          and ObjectType = 'None' )
group by 
    v.ObjectType1, v.ObjectType2, v.EnterDirection, v.Direction
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Just `left join` two queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    * -- Your operation
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM FirstQuery
) FQ LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT * FROM SecondQuery
) SQS ON FQ.ObjectType = SQS.ObjectType1 AND 
         FQ.EnterDirection = SQS.EnterDirection AND 
         FQ.Direction = SQS.Direction -- SemiTruck
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT * FROM SecondQuery
) SQT ON 
        FQ.ObjectType = SQT.ObjectType2 AND 
        FQ.EnterDirection = SQT.EnterDirection AND 
        FQ.Direction = SQT.Direction -- Truck
```